# C linux equivalent of windows QueryPerformanceCounter

Tags: c, linux, winapi, cpu

Is there an equivalent C function in linux for reading the CPU counter and its frequency?

I am looking for something similair to QueryPerformanceCounter function that reads the 64bit counter in modern CPU's

Comment: What is GetWPC? There's no such function in the Win32 API.

Answer (score 15):

[`clock_gettime(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clock_gettime), with an argument of `CLOCK_REALTIME_HR`.

Answer (score 5):

clock_gettime() with CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW

Answer (score 1):

The HAVEGE library uses the CPU counter. Check out its source code [here](http://www.irisa.fr/caps/projects/hipsor/download.php). The relevant file is src/hardtick.h.